# Difference between a newton balance and a newton meter

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

My thoughts is that a newton balance is one of those weighing scales that you stand on but it is calibrated in Newtons rather than Kilograms/Pounds. And a newton meter is like a hook where you hang stuff and it tells you the force. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"newton meter" is a unit, product of "newtons" (force) and "meters" (distance). It is a unit of energy, equivalent to "joule". It is also a unit of torque.

Force gauges come in a variety of forms, often identified by the technology or application (e.g. "load cell). But I've never seen one called a "newton meter".

Comment: @photon, keep in mind that while work and torque both have units of newton-meters, torque is NOT work.  It's easily possible to put torque on an object (e.g., lug nuts when you are changing a tire) without doing any work on that object, because the force you apply to a lever arm doesn't move through any distance.  For this reason, I advocate assigning work the unit of Joules and torque the unit of newton-meters.